# Scrap-work Methods

Tags: workflow, drawing, sketching, best-practice

Should one start their scrap-work / mockups in an ordinary notebook or scrap-paper to be thrown away ?

What is the recommended practice?

- Keep older drawings ?
- Throw them away ?

Is it better to sketch in pen or pencil ?

- Produce permanent work ?
- Leave space for change ?

Is there an attachment similar to Moleskine that can be made with Graphic design practice ? I have seen some carry around large drawing pads/books. Unfortunately I am on the move and would prefer something a bit smaller.

To sum up the question :

*Is there a certain format AIGA (that is the association for Designers right ?) recommends people to use for preliminary design ?*

Comment: No, there is not a certain format AIGA recommends people to use for preliminary design ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To answer your questions by order I'd say :

> Keep older drawings

Even a crappy one can be a source of inspiration one day.

> Any medium would do the trick.

Try many and choose 2 or 3 at the end. Stick with it if you enjoy using them. You can even use computerized drawing tools, too.

> It depends on what you're working on. For example, for web design, there are lots of pre-designed paper which leave a lot of spaces *everywhere* to allow room for comments and modifications.

For print and magazine, it's more like a *permanent work*. If one mockup doesn't suit you, retry with another paper :)

> You can sketch on any thing. Since it's not a final work.

If you like drawing on small books/pads, go for it. *It must be a pleasure first.* But if it needs to be precise, with a lots of comments or to be used by someone else afterward, you should use some large drawing pads.

Answer (score 6):

Do whatever removes the obstacles to working. Don't get hung up on the medium (paper vs. pixels) or the size or the permanence. I sketch in small notebooks, in Photoshop, on a wipe-off board, on the back of an envelope if I have nothing else to hand. It's convenient to have it all in one spiral-bound notebook, but don't let the lack of it prevent you from sketching, or working.